# How can i unescape special characters in the URL?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a Wcf service which accepts a parameter in the format '%%032000007777?'. In .net framework 4.0 we used to encode it once and be able to send the data by adding the following element in config file.

```
<system.net>
<settings>
  <httpListener unescapeRequestUrl="false"/>
</settings>
 </system.net>
```

Now we have migrated the service to3.5 framework and the HttpListener element is not available here. Is there anything else we can use to achieve this task?

What I tried - 
I added  element to the config file to check if it could work

```
    <uri>
  <iriParsing enabled="true" />
  </uri>
```

Also tried adding

```
    <uri>
    <schemeSettings>
    <add name="http" 
    genericUriParserOptions="DontUnescapePathDotsAndSlashes"/>
    </schemeSettings>
     </uri>
```

Both of these don't work, so I am not sure what I should do next.

This is my api

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/players/{id}/pin/validate", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    PlayerResponse ValidatePlayerPin(string id, ValidatePlayerPinRequest pinRequest);
```

When I encode the parameter twice I am able to hit my API and get the data in original form but I need it to work with single encoding? Is there any approach that I may be missing?

Comment: Use : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string) there is also a Encode method.

Comment: How can i add this in the config file. I cannot encode/decode in my code since the api call doesn't hit any service itself.

Comment: Where is the encoding?  Don't see anything in the posting.  The encoding should be HtmlEncode.

Comment: Before passing the value in the url, we encode it manually and then send it. Now if i encode it twice and send , it goes to the mentioned service url but it doesn't when i pass with single encoding. This happens because the HTTP framework itself decoded once. I want to skip past that, so that i can recieve data with single encoded value.

Comment: There are different types of encoding.  I do not know which type(s) you are using.  InnerText needs to be encoded with HtmlEncode(string (or equivalent) to eliminate special characters.  If your HTML body consists of lots of tags you could Encode the entire body using Convert 64 base string and send the 64 base string instead of tags. Then on Server side convert back to original tag data.